# Return multiple values from the same column in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: an image of my DB]

Return multiple values by select one column in the same table

which if i want to inquire about the manager name i write this code

```
select empname from employees, departments 
where employees.empid=departments.managerid
```

> > > > that will return (just manager names)

And if i want to inquire  about employees names,, i will write

```
select empname from employees
```

> > > > that will return (all employees name)

**

> i need a code to make both in one statement

**

Comment: edit the question add some sample data & desired result.

Comment: their is no manager name in departments table

Comment: create table departments 
(deptID int primary key, DeptName varchar(20), EmpID int foreign key referenes employess(empid) )
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
create table employess 
(empID int primary key, EmpName varchar(20), deptID int foreign key referenes departments(deptid))

Comment: _ahmed , ali , maher in a row and ali in a row_? Shouldn't it be in columns? Your questions doesn't make sense

Comment: Can you kindly share sample data from both tables and desired result?

Comment: i thinks it's obvious and i don't know if is right or wrong database structure
,,,,,,,,,,but the question is ????? how to return two relational values from one column in the same table
......the tables structure's pic is up....thnx for u r time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    select e.empname employeeName, m.empname managerName
from employees e , departments d,employees m 
where e.deptid=d.deptid and d.managerid=m.empid
```

Comment: or by where

ٍٍSelect e.empname employeeName, m.empname managerName
from employees e , departments d,employees m 
where e.deptid=d.deptid and d.managerid=m.empid

Answer (score 0):

Try this this `sql` query , by giving same `table` two alias names

```
SELECT A.empname,
       A.empname AS managername,
       A.departments
FROM employees A
     INNER JOIN employees B ON A.empID = B.managerID;
```

Comment: but their is a duplicated values which i write this code

Comment: select a.empname,b.empname as managerName from employees a , employees b , departments 
where b.deptid=departments.managerid

Comment: select with distinct than your coulmn which is going to show duplicate

Comment: not solved
select distinct a.empname,b.empname as managerName from employees a , employees b , departments 
where b.empid=departments.managerid

Comment: Can you send me script of create table for the same table please.. let me try

Comment: how could i write a script or a code int his page??

Comment: In job title you have jobtitle = Manager or JobTitle =Employee ??

Comment: You can use 2 table i think , on the basis of  DepartmentID_PK =DepartmentID_FK than get the ManagerID and select EMp ID and EMName from Employee Table ....